# Move Web Sites and Site Collection from Test to Production without access to the servers

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, deployment

We have two environments for our SharePoint 2010 installation: Test environment and Prod environment. We are not coding or doing heavy customizations and we are covering our needs somehow with SharePoint Designer 2010.

The problem we are facing is that when we want to move our modifications from test to production, we don't have any "clean" way of doing it, since we don't have access to any of the servers where the SharePoint installations are.

This means we cannot use PowerShell or SharePoint Solutions. We are really limited from this point of view. Is there any way, beside of re-doing in production what we've done in test, of easily moving our Web Sites from one environment to the other?

Just to mention, we also have access to SharePoint Designer in our Production Environment.

Thanks for the help.de

Answer (score 0):

You should have permission at Admin level, so that you can create site collection and can save web as a template.
If you such permission then save sites as template n try to res-store in production server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We tried this approach but we are not interested in deploy de ENTIRE Site Collection, just some customizations to web sites like Web Parts, Layouts, Content Types.... that leaves a Site Template out of the game. Besides, the size limitation is a problem for us.